# Validating and then redirecting to a post route in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, redirect, laravel

Is it possible to redirect the user to a POST route in Laravel.
I have 2 forms. *form-one* is sent to the Route containing *form-two* and *form-two* is sent to the *final* Route and then it is validated. If `$validator->fails()` for *form-two* is a truthy value at the *final* Route I want to send the user back to *from-two* but it is a **POST Route**.

```
Redirect::to('Form-Two')->withErrors($validator);
```

I tried using this but it failed maybe because it only works for Get routes. One thing I thought of doing was to redirect the user to a Get Route and then post the data to *form-two* from that Get Route, but that sounds stupid. Is there any cleaner way to do this. I'm a newbie.

**Form Two:**

```
Route::post('form-two', array('before' => 'csrf', function()
{
    $formOneData= Input::all();
    $rules = array(...);

    $validator = Validator::make($formOneData, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('Form-One')->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

**Final Page:**

```
Route::post('final', array('before' => 'csrf', function()
{
    $finalData = Input::all();
    $rules = array(...);

    $validator = Validator::make($finalData, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('Form-Two')->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

Comment: `withErrors` stores the errors on the session. Maybe you can try to leverage that fact.

Comment: Than you for your suggesting, but still I need to send the user back to the form-two page so that he can make necessary changes. Is is possible to POST data to a route from routes.php file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't particularly a Laravel issue, this requires you to understand how HTTP redirects work. When you send a redirect to a browser, you are sending the browser a 302 redirect with a URL to redirect to. Browsers will redirect making a GET request to the URL provided. You could potentially change the response code to 307 which asks the browser to do the redirect with the same method as was originally called with a security message **but** it is a bad idea to rely on this as it is implemented differently across browsers. Also Laravel would require you to build a custom response object with your own headers.

To keep your code compatible across browsers it is better practice to separate GET and POST logic. This is why returning views directly from a POST route is generally a bad idea.

The way I see this you really need to be looking to re-factor and rework how your forms work if you want the functionality you are aiming for.

Comment: I guess you are right... I make it a bit clumsy. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try to re factor it.