# How to avoid returning views from post pages in Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, post, view

I've seen in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863154/validating-and-then-redirecting-to-a-post-route-in-laravel?rq=1) about Laravel that it's supposedly a bad idea to try and return a view from a Post method in your controllers:

> To keep your code compatible across browsers it is better practice to separate GET and POST logic. This is why returning views directly from a POST route is generally a bad idea.

I ran into this [personally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143578/laravel-form-over-multiple-pages) while trying to construct a multi-page form in Laravel since validation redirects will not work when you're trying to return to a view that has a POST route.

My question is, *how* do you avoid returning views from post routes in Laravel? I use post routes a good deal since my pages frequently need to display previously entered information from prior pages. If I don't use POST, what's the best way to securely provide that information, so I can use things like the `Redirect::back()` and generally follow better coding practices?

I'm a bit of a newbie to web programming, especially Laravel, so I don't want to form bad habits. But I figure there must be a better answer to this conceptually than just using JavaScript and AJAX all the time, or doing crazy hacks to get the redirects to work with POST routes.

Comment: Always redirect after `POST` to avoid duplicate form submissions and so on. If you have to show a view, create a seperate `GET` request for it, then redirect to it from `POST`.

Comment: How do I get my Request data to the view, then? I'm often retrieving very large collections of data after a post request, and it doesn't seem like a good idea to pass hundreds of variables using GET. Or is that not true for Laravel?

Comment: I think you should retrieve those data in your get request.

Comment: I may be getting confused with some of my prior work in non-framework PHP, where POST was basically just how you send data without having to put it in the URL. Is laravel handling these requests more literally?

Comment: I think the concept is no different, whether it is framework or not. GET is simply used to retrieve data from the server and POST to post data from client to the server. Once the data posting is done, let GET handle request from server to the user.

Comment: A standard action for me, for instance, is entering an item in a form, creating a new entry in the DB, and then returning a lot of data that is associated with that entry so the user can view it on the next page. If I'm inserting the data using post, and getting feedback from the DB as I do so, how can I get that data to the view if I'm redirecting using GET?

Comment: Instead, you should fetch the data from DB in GET method.

Comment: What I'm saying is that that fetching process is dependent on data that was inserted during the POST process. For instance, the post process returns the ID of the entry you just submitted to the next form, or the form itself contains data that is both supposed to be inserted and is also used for retrieval. So there is data that the GET method would need in order to fetch any data from the DB, it can't just do it by itself, it doesn't have enough information. My question is how can I get those variables there securely?

Comment: AFAIK there is a `withInput()` method to redirect with input data, for other data I guess you would just use `with()`. You could post another question if you feel like it.